# How to determine if the communication is from APIGateway in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We are considering configuring Lambda to send requests from EventBridge and APIGateway.
In that case, I do not know how to determine the process from APIGateway in the Lambda process.

I have looked into using custom headers, etc., but since I have set the use of Lambda proxy integration to True, I am thinking in the direction of not being able to use custom headers.

Comment: Are you asking how your Lambda code can determine which service (APIGateway or EventBridge) invoked a given Lambda execution?

Answer (score 0):

Your Lambda handler code can check the event payload to determine the sending service.  The Lambda event objects for [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events-structure.html) and [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format) have different formats.   For instance, a payload with a `rawPath` key is from API Gateway.  A `detail` key in the payload means EventBridge sent it.